# run common query for all derived DAO class on schedule

Tags: java, jdbc, scheduling, dao, spring-jdbc

I have an abstract class that contains common methods:

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> implements IFindTradeDAO {


    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Override
    public List<Trade> findOne(final int eventId) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(getOneQuery(), new Object[]{eventId}, new RowMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Event> getAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(getAllQuery(), Event.class);
    }


    protected abstract String getOneQuery();

    protected abstract String getAllQuery();

}
```

The derived class which provides type specific queries:

```
@Repository
public class TypeA extends AbstractDAO implements IFindTradeDAO {

    private static final String FIND = "sql/findA.sql";

    private static final String GET = "sql/getA.sql";


    @Override
    protected String getOneQuery() {
        return FIND;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getAllQuery() {
        return GET;
}

@Repository
public class TypeB extends AbstractDAO implements IFindTradeDAO {

    private static final String FIND = "sql/findB.sql";

    private static final String GET = "sql/getB.sql";


    @Override
    protected String getOneQuery() {
        return FIND;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getAllQuery() {

    }

}
```

Given I have this class structure, I want to invoke the `getAllQuery()` for all the derived class sql e.g. for `TypeA` and `TypeB` on schedule using

`org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;`

```
   @Component
    public class GetAllEvents {

        @Scheduled
        public void processUnprocessedEvents() {
           //invoke getAllQuery for all DAOS and combine results

        }

    }
```

I am not quite sure how I can derive a `Component` that will invoke all? Is there technique or example I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try injecting both `TypeA` and `TypeB` in `GetAllEvents` and call their corresponding methods inside `processUnprocessedEvents`?

Comment: I have many dao implementation for each types and it seemed odd to autowire and call each.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java programmer, but in .NET you'd need to put them all into some type of list or array, and call the function on each item.

So maybe create a method called Add(IFindTradeDAO dao) which adds each one to a list. And then call the method on each of those items.